# How to print variables with #define like #define STR(M) = value of M

Tags: c, c-preprocessor

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define STR /*~~Complete this line~~*/
/* such that the output of the code is

M = 10
N = 5

*/

#define N 5
#define M 10

int main() {
printf(STR(M));
printf("\n");
printf(STR(N));
return 0;
}
```

We have to print M = 10 and N = 5 to the console.
I don't know how do we do that. Please help me. The question is well explained in the code itself.

Comment: `#define STR(X) #X " = %d", X`

Comment: @md5 - Why as a comment?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

<s>`#define STR(x) printf(#x "=%d",x)`</s>

I misread the question..when you use it in printf..use
 `#define STR(x) "%s = %d ",#x,x`
or
 `#define STR(x) #x "=%d",x`

Comment: What if we had puts instead of printf ?

Comment: Ah try once...you can check it in a compiler...

Comment: Doesn't work the same way.

Comment: gives me errors like puts has too many arguments to function call.

Comment: It doesn't work..but afaik my given solution works...

Comment: It obviously works with printf but not with puts. :)

Comment: That's what I said...I will try to find  more later

Comment: This does not work. Consider an expansion of `printf(STR(M));` -> `printf( printf(#x "=%d",x));` ...

Comment: who said that I would use it that way? I can use it simply like this `STR(x)` I gave the answer thinking that. otherwise I would gave the other way..which I gave and changed it..check my edit history.@EdHeal

Comment: The question states its usage as `printf(STR(M));`

Answer (score 2):

Here you go:

```
#define STR(x)  "%s=%d",#x,x
```

Please read up about macros

Comment: What if we were using puts instead of printf ?

Comment: @AshwaniJha - The you'd be out of luck

Comment: Why are you using macros sin the first place? Anyway why start changing the goal of the question?

Comment: Just a coding question in my college. I am in no mood of using it. :P

Comment: @EdHeal Any idea of making it work with puts ?

Comment: @EdHeal why use macros? Because the question wants the name printed as well as its value.

Comment: I explained. Just a coding question in my college. Only knowing is enough.

Comment: And I am new to stackoverflow. Can someone tell me why my questions keep getting downvoted? Has it something to do with the way I write the question?

Comment: @WeatherVane The question wants us to use Macros only. Read the code.

Comment: @AshwaniJha I did, which is why I posted the previous comment. Read the comment. This answer does not print the name.

Comment: @WeatherVane Yeah. Did I offend you? I was just saying.

Comment: I have updated the answer to include the name being printed